# How do I initialize an array of complex numbers so the properties such as phase, magnitude show up

Tags: c#, winforms, complex-numbers

so I have two forms. One form gets numbers and calculates a complex number and saves it to a form1 array. Everything is being passed and calculated correctly. I get my complex array no problem. The problem is when I try to get the phase of the Complex number. I know magnitude and phase are properties of the Complex struct so that I can just do load_Results.Magnitude or load_Results.Phase and get the corresponding values, but it doesn't give me the option of having that as a property. Did I initialize them the wrong way in form 1? How can I make it possible for those properties to show up.

This is what shows up as my error:

```
Error   24  'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Magnitude' and no extension method 'Magnitude' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Form 1

```
 public static  double[] freqList;
 public static Complex[] load_Results;


public form 1()
{           InitializeComponent();
            freqList = new double[801];
            load_Results = new Complex[801];

}

private void click_view(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // part that fails
Graph.Series[0].Points.AddXY(freqList,load_Results.Magnitude);
}
```

Form 2

```
private void test()
        {                    
             form1.load_Results[i] = Calculations(form1.freqList[i]);


        }
public Complex Calculations(double freq)
        {   Complex cval = new Complex();
            double mag, phase;
            //does math stuff to calculate mag and phase
            cval = Complex.FromPolarCoordinates(mag, phase);
            return (cval);
        }
```

Comment: Try to get in the habit of using C# naming and syntactic conventions. Variable do not get underbars: say `loadResults`, not `load_Results`.  Use whole words: `frequency`, not `freq`.  Don't put unnecessary parentheses in: `return value;` not `return (cval);`

Answer (score 0):

load_Results is an array which contains elements type of Complex. You need to get Magnitude property from each element of that array and return that. For example:

```
Graph.Series[0].Points.AddXY(freqList, load_Results.Select(x => x.Magnitude).ToArray());
```